Authentication problem in Teams app using teamsjs-v2
I have some authentication problems with my Microsoft Teams application.
I am using Auth0 for authentication and teamsjs-v2 for building the Teams app.
My Teams app uses the authentication.authenticate in the @microsoft/teams-js npm package which opens a popup where the auth flow is taken care of as the documentaion explains.
The popup successfully authenticates the user using Auth0 and stores the auth token in local storage, and then the popup is closed.
The problem is that when the popup is closed and the user is returned to the Teams app (the caller of authentication.authenticate), then nothing is found in local storage.
If I debug and look in the local storage of the popup then evertything is there, but not in the actual Teams app. It seems like they are not sharing the same local storage, even though its the same domain.
Even  more strange is that this problem only occur when using Teams in the web browser, everything works perfect when using the Windows Teams client which indicates that it should work.
The following is the code that initiates the popup where the authentication happens. In the successCallback nothing is found in local storage.
        import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

        microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
            url: window.location.origin + '/teams/login/start',
            width: 450,
            height: 800,
            successCallback: (result: any) => {
                console.log('Success successCallback');
                successCallback();
            },
            failureCallback: (reason: any) => {
                console.log(reason);
            },
        } as microsoftTeams.authentication.AuthenticatePopUpParameters);

Setup:
"@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.25.0",
"@angular/core": "14.2.0",
Why does it not work when using Teams in browser, while it works fine when using the Teams windows client?
